# GitHub pages for personal site. How to deploy a folder

Tags: github-pages

If I am using GitHub pages for my personal site, how should manage my source files? I have a simple setup which works.

But I understand I can't using Jekyll plugins with GitHub pages. If I want to use Grunt for example to optimise my images, for a usual app/site, it will produce output in say a `dist/public` folder, which I will then deploy. But I want to still use GitHub to manage my source files, how should I do it?

Answer (score 5):

Depending of repository kind your using, a User/Organization (**UO**) site or a Project site (**P**), sources and pages will be versionned in :

- User/Organization - sources : **sources**, pages: **master**
- Project - sources : **master**, pages: **gh-pages**

Note: The pages branch is mandatory, but the sources branch name can be changed.

#### Setup

- Initialize an empty github repository : **github.com/userName.github.io** for **UO** or **github.com/repositoryName** for **P**

Locally, initialize your local repository :

- Go to source folder `cd /home/username/www/yoursite` or anything you want
- git init
- `git remote add origin git@github.com:userName/userName.github.io.git` (**UO**) or `git remote add origin git@github.com:userName/repositoryName.git` (**P**)
- `git checkout -b sources` (**UO**) or `git checkout master` (**P**)
- in your .gitignore add your `dist/public`. As you are currently on `master` we will ignore it an version it in an other branch
- git add -A
- git commit -m "base sources". You now have committed your sources.
- `git push origin sources` (**UO**) or `git push origin master` (**P**) push your sources in the appropriate branch
- `cd dist/public`
- `touch .nojekyll`, this file tells gh-pages that there is no need to build a Jekyll site
- `git init`
- `git remote add origin git@github.com:userName/userName.github.io.git` (**UO**) or `git remote add origin git@github.com:userName/repositoryName.git` (**P**)
- `git checkout master` (**UO**) or `git checkout -b gh-pages` (**P**) put this repository on the appropriate branch
- your `grunt` task here
- `git add -A`
- `git commit -m "first build"` commit your site code
- `git push origin master` (**UO**) or `git push origin gh-pages` (**P**)

You now have pushed your code and pages in two different branches. They will now be pushed depending on where you are :

#### pushing sources

- `cd yourWorkingDirestory`
- `git add -A`
- `git commit -m "your commit message"`
- `git push origin sources` (**UO**) or `git push origin master` (**P**)

#### pushing pages

- `cd yourWorkingDirestory/dist/public`
- `git add -A`
- `git commit -m "your commit message"`
- `git push origin master` (**UO**) or `git push origin gh-pages` (**P**)